# How can I fix this tearing in fullscreen video with Radeon card?

Tags: video, radeon, tearing

Ever since I 'm on ubuntu 10.10 now 12.04 I'm having the some trouble with any video that I play in fullscreen, the image gets a horizontal cut, like this:

[image]

In ubuntu 10.10 I had a nVidea GTS 250 graphic card, and now I have an onboard Ati 3200HD video and I get the some results, doesn't matter which player I use (mplayer, vlc, or even a flash videos on fullscreeen get cut like this).

I don't know where to look, what setting change, what to install. I need help to get this fixed. It is driving me crazy

Right now I'm on ubuntu 12.04 x64 and I got Ubuntu's default graphics drivers installed.

Comment: To help you we need to know if you are using the open-source radeon drivers or the ones provieded by AMD (FGLRX). Did you install any additional graphics drivers after setting up your new system? If so then please follow darent's answer to enable "tear free" video from the AMD Catalyst settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of video tearing. If you have installed the catalyst drivers, search an option related to it. I think it was called AMD "tear-free" but I don't remember exactly  the name (long time using NVIDIA cards), and activate it.